# Not sure why typedef is being used when a struct tag has been set

Tags: c, struct

Considering the following code:

```
struct TreeNode {
  int key;
  struct TreeNode *left;  
  struct TreeNode *right;
};


struct ListNode {
  int key;
  struct ListNode *next;
};
```

I understand this as two structs with individual struct tags. And that the declaration (if I understand correctly):

```
struct ListNode *next;
```

Is creating a pointer that points to a struct of type ListNode. And that

```
struct ListNode node1;
```

Is creating a struct of type ListNode. 
However, I do not understand the following two lines:

```
typedef struct TreeNode *TreeNodePtr;
typedef struct ListNode *ListNodePtr;
```

If this is creating a pointer that points to a struct node of type TreeNode/ListNode I do not understand the purpose of typedef in this situation.

Comment: It's an alias to save some typing.

Comment: What typing is it saving? What would have to be written if it wasn't included?

Comment: Typedefs are *intended* to confuse you. In most cases you don't need them.

Comment: typing is saved ? means instead of writing big name, you can give one small name using typedef  with same properties

Comment: This convention abstracts away some of the noise in pointer declarations - instead of writing `struct TreeNode *tnode_ptr;`, you could simply write `TreeNodePtr tnode_ptr;`, which is a little easier to read.  Hiding the "pointer-ness" of a type can be a useful abstraction in some cases (the Windows API does it all over the place), but I am personally not fond of the convention.  Pointer semantics are special, and I'd rather make the "pointer-ness" of a type explicit.

Comment: @achal, you can do small typenames from longer ones for local usage... you also avoid the `struct` keyword as the final name is the name of a new type in the program, so you can use it without qualifying it as a `struct something`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef struct TreeNode *TreeNodePtr;
```

allows you to type

```
TreeNodePtr p;
```

instead of

```
struct TreeNode *p;
```

Note : People commonly do

```
typedef struct TreeNode TreeNode;
```

this allows

```
TreeNode tn;
```

This can also be done in the struct definition itself (a struct tag, but yr example doesn't have it)

```
struct TreeNode {
  int key;
  struct TreeNode *left;  
  struct TreeNode *right;
} TreeNode;
```

Also Note - in c++ this is not needed, a struct (or class) in c++ is always 'its own tag'

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense thank you. I was thinking typedef was for struct in that case.

Comment: i added a comment about that

Answer (score 0):

The typedef in this context is for the pointer (so that you can write `TreeNodePtr` and have a pointer type instead of `struct TreeNode *`). This sort of definition is commonplace in the Windows header files:

```
typedef struct _WINUSB_SETUP_PACKET {
UCHAR   RequestType;
UCHAR   Request;
USHORT  Value;
USHORT  Index;
USHORT  Length;
} WINUSB_SETUP_PACKET, *PWINUSB_SETUP_PACKET;
```